# Restore SQL Server database using C# with the layered solution architecture

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-restore

I have 3 tier application. I am trying to back up SQL Server database using C# code. I passed the selected folder path from the UI and execute the code in the Data layer. At the place of the select database it gives me an error.

> Failed to retrieve data for this request.Connection type is not valid.
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Enumerator.Process(Object connectionInfo, Request request)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExecutionManager.GetEnumeratorData(Request
>   req)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.GetDbCollation(String
>   dbname)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.GetDbComparer(Boolean
>   inServer)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.InitializeStringComparer()

I created a sample project with one layer and execute the code. The it works fine. I couldn't find the problem

I used the code as follows;

```
public void BackupData(string filePath)
    {
        Backup sqlBackup = new Backup();

        sqlBackup.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
        sqlBackup.BackupSetDescription = "ArchiveDataBase:" +
                                         DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
        string fileName = "\\ArchiveDataBase.bak";
        sqlBackup.BackupSetName = "Archive";

        sqlBackup.Database = "SanasaLibrarySystem";

        BackupDeviceItem deviceItem = new BackupDeviceItem(filePath + fileName, DeviceType.File);
        DataConnection dataConnection = new DataConnection();
        ServerConnection connection = new ServerConnection(dataConnection.DataBaseConnection);
        Server sqlServer = new Server(connection);

        Database db = sqlServer.Databases["SanasaLibrarySystem"];

        sqlBackup.Initialize = true;
        sqlBackup.Checksum = true;
        sqlBackup.ContinueAfterError = true;

        sqlBackup.Devices.Add(deviceItem);
        sqlBackup.Incremental = false;

        sqlBackup.ExpirationDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3);
        sqlBackup.LogTruncation = BackupTruncateLogType.Truncate;

        sqlBackup.FormatMedia = false;

        sqlBackup.SqlBackup(sqlServer);

    }
```

Comment: What are you using as connection string?? Obviously, there's something fishy about how you're trying to connect - investigate that first!

Comment: My connection string is as follows:
connectionString="server=(local);Initial Catalog=Master;Integrated Security=True;";
DataConnection is class which holds the SqlConnection using the above connection string

Comment: What if you just try to initialize the server like this: `Server sqlServer = new Server("(local)");` (or use the local machine's name here).

Comment: Its really a strange behavior....If I initiate the server as above it works fine. Can anybody explain it. 
Thanks marc your solution worked for me